# How can I add block colour to the CSS of my list?

Tags: html, list, css

I'm working on an chart using just HTML and CSS3 and I am able to easily style the lists colour overall but I'm looking to style just the top 30px of each list

This is how my char looks so far and what I would like to achieve:

[image]

CSS:

```
body {
    width:auto;
}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

ul {
    line-height:20px;
}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}



.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}


.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}


.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #dae2f2; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color: #2663A6;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tree">
<ul>
    <li>

             <a href="#"><span>Chairman / Owner</span><p>Name</p></a>

             <ul>
             <li>
             <a href="#">Managing Director</a>
             <ul>

             <li>
             <a href="#">Director</a>
             <li>
             <a href="#">Director</a>
             <li>
             <a href="#">Director</a>

             </ul>
             </ul>



    </li>
</ul>   



</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F3CQk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to go about it. Here's one.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/F3CQk/4/

```
span.accent {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: block;
    margin: -5px -10px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

<a href="#"><span class="accent">Chairman / Owner</span><span>Name</span></a>
```

Comment: Excellent! just what I'm after :) I did a similar thing with `span` also but I never made it `display:block` and add negative margins!

Answer (score 0):

You could just put two LI tags instead of one with border-botton:0px border-top:0px.